# How to install GCC on X-Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I'm at a bit of a loss, the problem is that I need to install GCC on X-Linux. Basically what's happening is I have been told to try and get wine on X-Linux...so I transfer the files over run the configure and I'm told I need GCC, so I download GCC only to find that I don't have a 'make' command...So I download the tar for the make command, turns out make needs a C compiler to run!

I'm stuck in a kind of chicken-and-the-egg loop here....help me!

Comment: All Linux distributions should have packages for GCC.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything to do with GCC on my system apart from the the GCC version my kernel was compiled against...

Comment: Generally you don't build on the actual target system, but on another host system where you "cross compile" and then upload to the target system.

Comment: Oh ok, I'm just looking into cross compiling now.. hopefully that will help

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - suggesting a cross compiler is unlikely to be an efficient answer here.  Realistically, a system which can run wine is going to be an intel architecture, and not one that someone would usually cross compile for from something else unless they were building a brand new distribution or using an automated build server as part of a development cycle.  The true answer will be to find the binary (or failing that, bootstrap) packages for the distribution in question.

Comment: Looking further, it is likely that this system is going to be missing many more of the dependencies for wine as well.  It may be a lot more efficient to switch to a compact installation of a more full featured distribution (for example some compact debian derivative, as is not popular even on little arm-based boards, only x86 in this case), or else port the windows code to run natively on linux.

Answer (score 2):

A GNU Make source tarball contains a `build.sh` script to resolve this chicken-and-egg situation. From the README:

> If you need to build GNU Make and have no other make program to use,
>   you can use the shell script build.sh instead. To do this, first run
>   configure as described in INSTALL. Then, instead of typing make to
>   build the program, type sh build.sh. This should compile the program
>   in the current directory. Then you will have a Make program that you
>   can use for ./make install, or whatever else.

Comment: No.  That might get around the problem of not having make to make make, but the script is not going to substitute for a missing C compiler!